# PdfViewr proplem save page

Tags: java, android

I am using PdfViewr.

I want to open pdf on the last page, which is not working. I have tried many times but its not working.

I used this code

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.newpdf);
        pdfView = (PDFView) findViewById(R.id.pdfView);
        displayFromAsset(SAMPLE_FILE);
    }

    private void displayFromAsset(String assetFileName) {
        pdfFileName = assetFileName;

        pdfView.fromAsset(SAMPLE_FILE)
                .defaultPage(pageNumber)
                .enableSwipe(true)
                .swipeHorizontal(false)
                .onPageChange(this)
                .enableAnnotationRendering(true)
                .onLoad(this)
                .scrollHandle(new DefaultScrollHandle(this))
                .spacing(10)
                .load();
    }


    @Override
    public void onPageChanged(int page, int pageCount) {
        pageNumber = page;
        setTitle(String.format("%s %s / %s", pdfFileName, page + 1, pageCount));
    }


    @Override
    public void loadComplete(int nbPages) {
        PdfDocument.Meta meta = pdfView.getDocumentMeta();
        printBookmarksTree(pdfView.getTableOfContents(), "-");

    }

    public void printBookmarksTree(List<PdfDocument.Bookmark> tree, String sep) {
        for (PdfDocument.Bookmark b : tree) {

            Log.e(TAG, String.format("%s %s, p %d", sep, b.getTitle(), b.getPageIdx()));

            if (b.hasChildren()) {
                printBookmarksTree(b.getChildren(), sep + "-");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I save pdf's last page, and I need to implement this for my app. Any help?

Thank you.

Comment: where u stored pageNumber  ? in SharedPrefs / DB. If u pass pageNumber   as 10 what happening

Comment: hi thank you for help can you help me with this code

Comment: You have to store pagenumber globally. You can use preference or db or any global variable to store pagenumber.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use preference to store page number so it can be globally access and not change with class instance.

```
    public static final String MY_PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.newpdf);
        pdfView = (PDFView) findViewById(R.id.pdfView);
        displayFromAsset(SAMPLE_FILE);
    }

    private void displayFromAsset(String assetFileName) {

    if(!getFileName().equals(assetFileName)){
           setPageNumber(0);
           setFileName(assetFileName);
     }
        pdfView.fromAsset(assetFileName)
                .defaultPage(getPageNumber())
                .enableSwipe(true)
                .swipeHorizontal(false)
                .onPageChange(this)
                .enableAnnotationRendering(true)
                .onLoad(this)
                .scrollHandle(new DefaultScrollHandle(this))
                .spacing(10)
                .load();
    }


    @Override
    public void onPageChanged(int page, int pageCount) {

        setPageNumber(page)
        setTitle(String.format("%s %s / %s", pdfFileName, (getPageNumber() + 1), pageCount));
    }


    @Override
    public void loadComplete(int nbPages) {
        PdfDocument.Meta meta = pdfView.getDocumentMeta();
        printBookmarksTree(pdfView.getTableOfContents(), "-");

    }

     public void setPageNumber(int pageNumber) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putInt("page_number", pageNumber);
            editor.apply();
        }

        public int getPageNumber() {
            SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
            return prefs.getInt("page_number", 0);
        }
    public void setFileName(String fileName) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putString("file_name", fileName);
            editor.apply();
        }

        public String getFileName() {
            SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
            return prefs.getString("file_name", "");
        }
    public void printBookmarksTree(List<PdfDocument.Bookmark> tree, String sep) {
        for (PdfDocument.Bookmark b : tree) {

            Log.e(TAG, String.format("%s %s, p %d", sep, b.getTitle(), b.getPageIdx()));

            if (b.hasChildren()) {
                printBookmarksTree(b.getChildren(), sep + "-");
            }
        }   
    }
```

Comment: Welcome.. Keep coding.. :)

Comment: i have 40 pdf the proplem is all pdf open in same page number how  fix this
thank you

Comment: @ahmmed You can use hashMap to store all pdf file page numbers in the set of pdf File Name and page number.

Answer (score 0):

Save your last page number every time and pass when you initialise pdf like:

```
pdfView.fromAsset(SAMPLE_FILE)

            .defaultPage(pageNumber) // enter your last page number
            .enableSwipe(true)
            .swipeHorizontal(false)
            .onPageChange(this)
            .enableAnnotationRendering(true)
            .onLoad(this)
            .scrollHandle(new DefaultScrollHandle(this))
            .spacing(10)
            .load();
```